# Unable to resolve module

Tags: javascript, java, react-native

I have a react-native app with a homemade library but it appears every time this error and I don't know what to do with this. If someone needs more code, tell me and I will include it because I don't know if you need more code to resolve it.

I already made that this error tells me, delete node_modules and cache and reinstall, but it doesn't work.

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-silent-ping-sms` from `C:\Users\erikc\Flyve\proyecto1\index.js`: Module `react-native-silent-ping-sms` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\erikc\Flyve\proyecto1\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:183:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\erikc\Flyve\proyecto1\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\erikc\Flyve\proyecto1\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:273:16)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\erikc\Flyve\proyecto1\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:261:42)
    at dependencies.map.result (C:\Users\erikc\Flyve\proyecto1\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:391:31)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\erikc\Flyve\proyecto1\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:388:18)
    at C:\Users\erikc\Flyve\proyecto1\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:261:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\erikc\Flyve\proyecto1\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
```

Comment: Try going to android folder by cd android/ and then
clean it by ----- ./gradlew clean , and try to bulid it again

Comment: check your package.json `react-native-silent-ping-sms` is installed or not ? if yes then have you link that library ?

Answer (score 0):

The error means the module `react-native-silent-ping-sms` is either not installed or not linked using `react-native link`.

First, try doing

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules && npm install && npm cache clean --force
```

Or you can do the above with one simple command, just install `react-native-surrender` globally using `npm install -g react-native-surrender` & then type `surrender`.

Then link `react-native-silent-ping-sms` using `react-native link` or `react-native link react-native-silent-ping-sms`

It should be resolved then :)

Answer (score 0):

It was installed in the package.json and I try cleaning cache every time. 
So I decided to upload it to the NPM page and install the library directly from the NPM page and it works perfectly.